# How to debug Smart Reply in notification?

Tags: android, android-emulator

With the release of Android 10, they announced a new feature called [Smart Reply](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights#smart_reply_in_notifications) (which already existed in Gmail/Messages apps) inside notifications.

Now, we have a lot a code around notifications in my app, and we use them a lot. For obvious reasons I want to test if our current implementation works correctly with those new [system generated contextual actions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions(boolean)).

Does anyone know how to manually trigger a Smart Reply in notification using Android 10 emulators ? I have been trying to make them appear all day (by creating a fake notification in my app and changing its content, like filling the content with an address, a phone number etc) without success.

Thanks !

Comment: could you resolve this problem ??
because i have the same problem, i have a mesaging app and i can not show suggetions on notifications

Comment: Did you find anything ?
I am also not able to make it work, I even tried how telegram is doing but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

does you notification has reply actions?

```
val remoteInput = RemoteInput.Builder(BigPictureSocialIntentService.EXTRA_COMMENT)
                    .setLabel(replyLabel)
                    .setChoices("Yes","No")// hardcoded responses for Android P
                    .build()
```

If you have hardcoded `setChoices(listOfReplies)` system will not supply smart replies .

```
//When you build action setAllowGeneratedReplies to true
val replyAction = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    R.drawable.ic_reply_white_18dp,
                    replyLabel,
                    replyActionPendingIntent)
                    .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                    .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
                    .build()
```

// set setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions to true for suggested actions

```
               .notificationCompatBuilder.setStyle()
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText("Hey lets meet for dinner at xx sretee Rd, New York Postocde")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        resources,
                        R.drawable.ic_person_black_48dp))

                .setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions(true)
                .setSubText(Integer.toString(1))
                .addAction(replyAction)
```

Having said that, the current emulator does not supply any smart replies, I am yet to test it on actual device running 10

also make sure the smart replies are enabled in the notif settings[image]

Comment: i did all this and i have not 'setChoices' and i can not see any suggestion